# ramificando um branch de um determinado commit e migrando commits subsquentes

Tags: git

Estava atualizando um repositório, criando sua documentação, para isso criei um novo branch chamado `master-guibook` um diretório "./docs" e um arquivo "book.json" no raiz do projeto, então abri o Editor do Gitbook.

Mas o Editor do Gitbook achou que por sua conta deveria voltar ao Branch Master, e não vi que ele fez o checkout para o master, fazendo assim algumas edições no master.

Não estou sabendo como migrar as edições de um certo commit até o fim do atual master par ao branch `master-gitbook"

Minha arvore atualmente está assim:

`master-gitbook               /branch-master-gitbook-porem-vazio
                            / 
master           m1---m2---m3---m4---m5---m6---m7---m8---m9---m10`

No caso como devo fazer para que os commits de m4 até m10 passem a pertencer ao branch `master-gitbook` podendo assim continuar meu trabalho?

E como não posso parar o trabalho, supondo que eu tenha um novo commit como abaixo

`master-gitbook               /branch-master-gitbook-porem-vazio
                            / 
master           m1---m2---m3---m4---m5---m6---m7---m8---m9---m10---m11`

tornar os commits de m4 até m10 pertencentes ao novo branch e manter m1 no branch `master`fazend que fiquem assim:

`master-gitbook               /---m4---m5---m6---m7---m8---m9---m10
                            / 
master           m1---m2---m3---m11`

Comment: Os commits de m4 em diante já foram "push"ados para o servidor? Ou permaneceram somente locais?

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato, considere como locais.

Answer (score 2):

Pode-se fazer o fast-forward do `master-gitbook` para `m10` e depois remover os commits `m4` a `m10` do `master`. Use os comandos abaixo (substitindo `mX` pelo hash SHA-1 do respectivo commit):

```
git checkout master-gitbook
git merge m10
git checkout master
git rebase -i m3
```

No editor de texto que será aberto, apague todas as linhas referentes aos commits `m4` a `m10`. Deverá ficar apenas as linhas `m11` em diante.

**Nota:** o comando `git merge m10` só funcionará como quer se o branch `master-gitbook` estiver ainda em `m3`. Caso contrário, será criado um commit de merge ao invés de ser feito um fast-forward ou deve-se usar `rebase` ao invés de `merge`.